# Does the bonus attack from "Polearm Master" have reach as well?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, weapons, reach

PHB p. 168: **Polearm Master**

> You gain the following benefits:
>
> - When you take the Attack action and attack with only a glaive, halberd, or quarterstaff, you can use a bonus action to make a melee attack with the opposite end of the weapon. This attack uses the same ability modifier as the primary attack. The weapon's damage die for this attack is a d4, and it deals bludgeoning damage. [...]

Do I use the same reach as the primary weapon as well?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Yes, your reach with the bonus attack is the same as your reach with the regular attack. The Reach weapon property states that:

> This weapon adds 5 feet to your reach when
>   you attack with it, as well as when determining your
>   reach for opportunity attacks with it (see chapter 9).

So whenever you make an attack with a Reach weapon, your reach is 5 feet more than usual. There's no restrictions placed on how you get that attack. As long as you're using the right weapon, you get the extra reach.

In this specific case, you're attacking with the opposite end of the weapon, but it's still the same weapon. Your reach will be 10ft if it's a Reach weapon, or 5ft otherwise.

Comment: While its not specifically mentioned here, it may be worth noting that the Quarterstaff doesn't have reach and therefore both the normal attack and the bonus attack are at standard 5ft reach.

Comment: @ChrisDavies Ah, good point! I totally missed that!

Comment: I would highlight near the start that the reach applies to the character who is holding the weapon, not to the weapon - this has been a point of confusion in the two groups I play in - when somebody has reach, it means that weapon has caused the CHARACTER, not the individual attacks thereof, to have reach.

Comment: @gburton That's not right - attacks with a reach weapon have reach, but if you're holding a reach weapon, you can't suddenly kick things 10 feet away from you.